# google map place search marker icon styling

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I search I google map, I am getting places marker icon with rounded red background as in below screenshot. I am trying to create the marker with exact same style in my application. I am using google map API for javascript v3.

Here is code to create the google map marker from the results of places api results.

> ```
>         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
>           map: $this.map,
>           position: place.geometry.location,
>           icon: {
>               url: place.icon,
>               size: new google.maps.Size(18,18),
>               origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
>               anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
>               scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(18, 18),
>
>             }
>
>         });
> ```

[image]

Live Example in [google map](https://www.google.co.in/maps/search/restaurant/@12.9289252,77.6289442,14z)

Comment: Just use icon like that

Comment: I can't find or create the icon for each type of place search, but google place search itself sending the [result with icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places). I unable to find the way to style it as like screenshot

Comment: Yes there is one icon in `place.icon` property you can use it but they look very ugly

Comment: Correct, that the reason I am trying to style it as like google map website. I they seems using the same icon but styled in good way

Comment: Nope they (red ones) aren't icons! actually google uses image grids to render your map so they are created as a whole on their servers

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of google maps, 
you can specify the marker icon with url to your image.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers

```
var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
var icons = {
  parking: {
    icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
  },
  library: {
    icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
  },
  info: {
    icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
  }
};

function addMarker(feature) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: feature.position,
    icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
    map: map
  });
}
```

Comment: Google map places api already sending the URL of the icon. But I want to know to style exactly like in the google map website!